# RegExp: find "//" followed by any symbol except space

Tags: javascript, regex

Title says it all. My intention is to insert a space by replacing the match with `"// "`.

So far I tried this:

```
\/\/\b(?! )
```

But this does not match strings such as `"//$..."`

Comment: Yes, probably, I'm not sure how to use it so it wouldn't be matched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead for a space:

```
\/\/(?! )
```

---

Although this answers your question as stated, I suspect you actually *don't* want to match when `//` is at the end of a line (which would qualify under your question's definition). If so, use a positive look ahead for a non whitespace char:

```
\/\/(?=\S)
```

Comment: Thanks, JS flavour: \/\/(?! )  I was so close.. :)

Comment: Quick question also if I want to exclude /// how should I define it?

Comment: @taut try `\/\/(?![\s\/])`

Comment: btw, you could also try `\/\/\B`, which is a non-word boundary

Comment: `\/\/\B` also won't match `//$...` as in the question, or `//` followed by any other non-`\w` symbol.